# How can I synchronize items with the cloud while my app is in the background?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, synchronization

In my iPad app, the user can enter data online or offline, storing the data in SQLite, and when the user goes online, he hits a "sync" button, whereupon the data will be synced up to the cloud.

If the user enters data offline, the data persists in the local SQLite DB. If the data is not yet synced, I set a badge to the number of records pending sync.

When the user starts up his iPad, he should get some alert on startup saying "There are 5 records pending to sync." Then all the pending records will be synced, without opening my app.

Has anyone come across a similar scenerio? Does anyone have any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

Before iOS 5.0 it was not possible to synchronize data with your application when the application was not running. However there were some scenarios when the app could e.g finish a download when the App was terminated but this background-processing is rather limited.

Now if you want to sync to the cloud and have the same data available on another iOS device or on a Mac app then I guess iCloud might be exactly what you are looking for.

So a possible scenario with iCloud might look like this:

1. You have your iCloud enabled App installed on two iPads
2. On both iPads you are logged in with your iCloud account (this has to match since iCloud is tied to a given Apple ID
3. When your App stores some data on `iPad1` it will automatically be synced to the cloud
4. On the same time this data is downloaded to the `iPad2` (which has to have internet connection) while your application is not yet launched. This is only possible with iCloud
5. When you now start your App on `iPad2` (even if it is now offline) you will have the current data available within your App.

However, if you are running your own server backend, and maybe need more control over the data on the server, iCloud might not (yet) fit your needs there. You might want to check out the documentation or the sample code for iCloud: [iCloud for Developers (Apple Developer Account required)](http://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php)

If you chose not to use iCloud then there is currently no way that you can sync data while your application is not running.

**Edit:**
A scenario without iCloud could look like this:

1. You enter Data on `iPad1` while offline and set the badge to the number of unsynced items
2. Later you have internet connection, so you start the app and the items can be synced to your server.
3. Your server stores the newly arrived entries and could now send a [Push notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) to your App which is installed on `iPad2` telling the user that there are `n` new entries on the server.

   - From that notification the user could now decide to open the app and the new items could then be downloaded to the `iPad2`.
   - If the user dismisses the notification then no data is downloaded until he starts your App the next time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I liked it. but without iCloud scenerio I m looking forward. You edit one scenerio matches with my current requirement but I don't want to open my app and want to sync the data when I turn-on my iPad. Is that possible ?

Comment: @user946178 Unfortunately this is not possible since apps can't do any processing in the background when they are not running at all.

Comment: Thanks Besi, I got it it's not possible. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do u know how can I run some task in background ?

Comment: Like stated the execution of background tasks is very limited. You'll find more information here: [Apple Developer: App States and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)